# How to print output of multiple txt file in tabular format with Python code?

Tags: python, output-formatting

I have tried to best fit my data set for more than 700 txt files with a single run. And I want the output parameter obtained from all files into a tabular format.I have tried in this way

```
def resid(params, x, ydata):
   decay = params['decay'].value
   phase = params['phase'].value
   omega = params['omega'].value
   amp = params['amp'].value
   ampb=params['ampb'].value
   phaseb=params['phaseb'].value
   #omegab = params['omegab'].value
   
   y_model =  (amp * np.sin(x*2*np.pi*omega+phase)+ ampb*np.sin(x*4*np.pi*omega+phaseb)) * np.exp(-x*decay)
   return y_model - ydata


filelist = glob.glob("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/B3/*.txt") 
#print(filelist)
for file in filelist:
   data = np.loadtxt(file)
   x = data[:,0]
   y = data[:,1]
   params = lmfit.Parameters()
   params.add('phase', 0.0,   min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
   params.add('omega',  10,   min=7, max=12)
   params.add('amp',     7,   min=0, max=10.0)
   params.add('decay', 0.05,  min=0, max=10.0)
   params.add('ampb',     3,  min=0, max=8.0)
   params.add('phaseb', 0.0,  min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
   #params.add('omegab', 18, min=16, max=20)   
   
   fit = lmfit.minimize(resid, params, args=(x, y), method='differential_evolution')
   #print("\n\n# Fit using differential_evolution:")
   #print(lmfit.report_fit(fit))
   for name, param in fit.params.items():
           if name=='phase':
               print('phase',' ' , param.value,' ',param.stderr, ) 
           elif name=='amp ':
               print('amp', '   ',param.value,'  ',param.stderr )
           elif name=='omega':
               print('omega', '  ',param.value,'  ',param.stderr)
           elif name=='decay':
               print('decay', '  ',param.value,'  ',param.stderr)
           elif name=='ampb':
               print('ampb', '   ',param.value,'  ',param.stderr)
           else: 
               print('phaseb','  ',param.value,'  ',param.stderr)
   print(fit.success)
```

I expect the output in this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUeqR.png)

but I have got values of each output  separately like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiVVd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty `dict` before the inner `for` loop, make the loop fill that `dict` with the params, and then print them all on 1 line after the `for` loop is done. The below example will print the values next to each other, separated with the TAB character, which should be readable enough but the "table" might not be perfectly aligned. If you want it to look better in terminal, there are some solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data). Alternatively you could dump the TAB- or comma-separated values to a file, then open that file e.g. with Excel.

```py
    ...
    params = {}
    for name, param in fit.params.items():
        if name == 'phase':
            params['phase'] = param.value
            params['phase_stderr'] = param.stderr
        elif name == 'amp':
            params['amp'] = param.value
            params['amp_stderr'] = param.stderr
        elif name == 'omega':
            params['omega'] = param.value
            params['omega_stderr'] = param.stderr
        elif name == 'decay':
            params['decay'] = param.value
            params['decay_stderr'] = param.stderr
        elif name == 'ampb':
            params['ampb'] = param.value
            params['ampb_stderr'] = param.stderr
        else: 
            params['phaseb'] = param.value
            params['phaseb_stderr'] = param.stderr
    print(
        params['phase'],
        params['amp'],
        params['omega'],
        params['decay'],
        params['ampb'],
        params['phaseb'],
        params['phase_stderr'],
        params['amp_stderr'],
        params['omega_stderr'],
        params['decay_stderr'],
        params['ampb_stderr'],
        params['phaseb_stderr'],
        sep="\t"
    )
```

Comment: @PrakashGyawali no need to thank me :) please just upvote the answer if you think it's useful, and if it solves your problem - mark it as accepted. Thanks!